# Modify the values of an array where a list of the same size contains values of another list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have these two lists :

```
List_large = ['a','b','c','d']
List_small = ['a','c']
```

And this array :

```
check = np.array([0]*len(List_large))
check
Out : array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I would like to have 1 in the array "check" in the positions of List_large having the values of List_small. Consequently, I would like to finally have this array :

```
array([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a list-comprehension using a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> List_large = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> List_small = ['a','c']
>>> np.array([1 if c in List_small else 0 for c in List_large])
array([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) method.

```
result = np.isin(List_large, List_small).astype(int)
```

If your version of numpy is small than 1.13.0, use `in1d` method.

```
result = np.in1d(List_large, List_small).astype(int)
```

Since `result = np.in1d(List_large, List_small)` method returns a *numpy* `array` of *boolean* values, you need to use `astype` method in order to obtain a *list* of *binary* values, `0` and `1`.

Output

```
array([1, 0, 1, 0])
```